# React native debugger doesn't not show. it's blank

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-debugger

The Redux DevTools are not appearing in the React Native Debugger even after attempting to reinstall the debugger, and toggling the DevTools for React and Redux. I installed the debugger using Homebrew version 4.1.12 with the following command:
brew install --cask react-native-debugger

Is there a solution to access the Redux DevTools in order to inspect the redux state?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install react-devtools with the following command:

```
yarn global add react-devtools@^4.22.0
```